# Is this related rates?

Tags: calculus

My question is data upload rate of data is

$$r=200+2t+10\pi\sin (\pi t) $$
Where $r$ is MB per hour  and $t$=time.

At $t=0$, there are $10000$ MB already on storage.

I am asked for how much data is on the system at $t=2$ and what the relationship is.  I have figured the relationship to be $s=10000+rt $ where $s$=storage and input $t=2$ into the original equation and input the output into the new equation along with $t=2$.

I don't know if I'm making any sense out of this at all!  Am I on the right track?

P.S. Sorry if the formatting is wrong or the question is stupid! First-time poster.

Update:  taking the intergral i get $1/2rt^2+10000t $ when inputting $r $ and $t $ at $t $=0 i get 0 which doesnt work! Help!

Comment: I believe you have to integrate the rate into the storage.

Comment: So intergrating $t $ into $s=10000+rt $ I get $1/2rt^2+10000t $ and inputting my time and data rates would give me my storage amount?  I am struggling a little with intergration and realy appreciate your help!

Comment: Can i bump this question.  Its driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret the data rate $r$ as time derivative of the storage size $s$: 
$$
\frac{ds}{dt} = 200+2t+10\pi\sin (\pi t)
$$
Integrating both sides regarding time $t$ gives
\begin{align}
s(t) - s(0) 
&= \int\limits_0^t 200+2\tau+10\pi\sin (\pi \tau) \, d\tau \\
&= [ 200 \tau + \tau^2 - 10 \cos(\pi\tau) ]_0^t \\
&= 200 t + t^2 -10 \cos(\pi t) + 10
\end{align}
Using the initial condition $s(0)=10000$ we get
$$
s(t) = t^2 + 200 t + 10010 - 10 \cos(\pi t)
$$
and $s(2) = 10404$.